# iPod plugged in

Tags: ipod

I've been sleeping with my iPod. 
But it's plugged in to the wall and I always put it in bed with me while charging .
Is it dangerous to have a plugged iPod in bed with you while sleeping .

Answer (score 1):

As with all things in life there are some risks you may want to be aware of here:

- You might get entangled into the cord and either endager yourself or damage the phone/cord/plug by ripping it out of the wall when you turn yourself
- You may end up laying on top of your phone leading to overheating and your bed catching fire
- Electro-magnetic radiation from the cord may or may not impact your sleep pattern
- One of the tracks you are listening to may be much louder than the others leading to a unpleasant wake up call in the middle of the night

OTOH I've never heard of anybody dying in their sleep due to a plugged in iPod so the probability of the more severe incidents is extremely low. And you could work around most of the risks above by getting a bluetooth headset and putting the iPod on a table besides your bed.